# Strange error with libnfc and NFC reader MF522-AN

Tags: python, nfc, spi

I have an NFC reader connected to a RaspberryPi through SPI, and configured with this tutorial: https://www.firefart.at/how-to-crack-mifare-classic-cards/

The problem is that when I run the command nfc-list I get this error:

```
pi@MYPI ~ $ nfc-list
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_spi Unable to wait for SPI data. (RX)
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_spi Unable to wait for SPI data. (RX)
No NFC device found.
```

I can't find the error, but the strange thing is that this same NFC reader is working find, also through SPI, using this Python library: https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python

You can see that uses the following parameters:

```
def __init__(self, dev='**/dev/spidev0.0**', spd=**1000000**):
    spi.openSPI(device=dev,speed=spd)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(self.NRSTPD, 1)
    self.MFRC522_Init()
```

Any ideas?

More info:

This is my /etc/nfc/libnfc.conf configuration, which is failing:

```
allow_intrusive_scan=true
name = "Breakout Board"
LIBNFC_LOG_LEVEL=3
connstring = pn532_spi:/dev/spidev0.0:1000000
```

Thanks.

Comment: very simple : libnfc is not compatible with MFRC522 :D

Comment: That's what I supposed, and that's why I finally choose to to buy another NFC: PN532 (FZ0834), which is is compatible with libnfc. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You need a C++ code for drive MF522-AN with raspberry Pi ? Why don't use the Python Lib ?

Comment: Where do you see C++? It's Python.

Comment: libnfc is written in C++, nfc-list is a function compiled from C++.So, my question was "Do you need C++ code for drive MF522-AN ?", in other case you can use your second option MFRC522-python !